# DropDownList Result not being Returned

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to create an Item that has an ItemType coming from another table. I am unable to get back the actual Type object from the Create page.  This is the code I have tried:

Models:

```
public class ItemType {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Item{ get; set; }
}

public class Item {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public virtual ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
}
```

In the ItemController, this is my create code:

```
    public ActionResult Create() {
        var itemTypeRepo = new ItemTypeRepository(context);
        ViewBag.ItemTypes = new SelectList(itemTypeRepo.GetAll(), "ID", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Item item) {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            context.Items.Add(item);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(item);
    }
```

In my Create.cshtml view I have tried:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("ItemType", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemType) 
</div>
```

This returns no value at all and throws an error "The value 'X' is invalid." Where X is the ID of the ItemType I selected. 
And

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ItemType.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.ItemType)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemType) 
</div>
```

This creates a stub ItemType object with the correct ID but does not insert it into the database since the object is not fully loaded.  If I look at ModelState object, I find that there is an error that the Name field is missing from ItemType object.

I also attempted to solve the problem using the second .cshtml code and adding this code:

```
public ActionResult Create(Item item) { 
    item.ItemType = context.ItemTypes.Find(item.ItemType.Id);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

This does not change the value of ModelState.IsValid from false even through it should.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a property ItemTypeId to your Item entity so that it acts as a foreign key.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemTypeId")]
    public virtual ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use that property for the dropdownlist:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ItemTypeId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ItemType)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemType) 
</div>
```

Comment: How do I link that to the ItemType object?  If I look in the database generated by the model, there is already a foreign key to the ItemType table.

Comment: It should be linked automatically because of the naming convention.

Comment: I tested it and it is not linked automatically and it does not fix the issue.

Comment: Strange. Maybe you can try to enforce it using an attribute. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the issue.  Your code does work!  The issue is that I had a [Required] Attribute on the virtual ItemType property.  I moved the required up to the ItemTypeId field and it worked. My code in my example missed that [Required] attribute.

Comment: Just an extra bit of information: you don't really need to add a `[Required]` attribute to a property of type `int`. The `[Required]` attribute just says "This can't be null," but since integers can't be null by default, you don't need to add the attribute. If you ever want an optional integer, just use `int?` instead of `int`.